# Returning a pointer to a ship in BattleShip game C++

Tags: c++, pointers, boolean, member

I am trying to teach myself C++ so I am doing a Battleship program. I have a Ship and Board class.

This version is fairly standard. The player enters the coordinates of a cell to try to hit a ship. The program stating if a ship is hit. If all cells occupied by a ship are hit, the program prints a message stating that that ship is sunk. After each attempt, the program prints the current state by showing the board with all successful attempts marked by `"*"` or `"x"`respectively.

I am having trouble implementing the `Ship *shipAt(int x, int y)` function in my Board class to keep account for the ship essentially this function returns a pointer to that ship. Otherwise it returns a null pointer.

I have a board for the Battleships

```
   a b c d e f g h i j
  +-------------------+
 0|                   |
 1|                   |
 2|                   |
 3|                   |
 4|                   |
 5|                   |
 6|                   |
 7|                   |
 8|                   |
 9|                   |
  +-------------------+
```

Here is my  the `bool Ship::includes(int x, int y)` function from my ship class that I am trying to implement to complete my shipAt function. I cut it down for brevity:

```
#include "Ship.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

//Would have been more member functions but I cut it down for brevity 

bool Ship::includes(int x, int y)
{
    bool include= false;

    if(x == x1)
    {
        if ((y>= y1) && (y<=y2))
        {
            include = true;
        }
        if ((y>= y2) && (y<=y1))
        {
            include = true;
        }
    }
    else if (y == y1)
    {
        if ((x>= x1) && (x<=x2))
            {
                include = true;
            }
        if ((x>= x2) && (x<=x1))
        {
            include = true;
        }
    }


    return include; 
}





    }
```

**Here is my Board Class. I am having trouble with the `Ship *shipAt(int x, int y)` function
For this function, if a ship occupies the cell (x,y) this function returns a pointer to that ship. Otherwise it returns a null pointer.**

```
#include "Board.h"
#include "Ship.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdexcept>


//member function definitions

Board::Board(void)
{
     char score[10][10] = {};
}

void Board::addShip(char type, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) 
{
    if(shipList.size()<10)
        {
            shipList.push_back(Ship::makeShip(type,x1,y1,x2,y2));
        }
}

void Board::print(void){

 cout<< "   a b c d e f g h i j"<< endl;
    cout <<"  +-------------------+"<< endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        // print the first character as part of the opener.
        cout << " " << i << "|" << score[i][0];
        for (int j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
           // only add spaces for subsequent characters.
           cout << " " << score[i][j];
        }
        cout << "          |" << endl;
    }
    cout <<"  +-------------------+"<< endl;

}

void Board::hit(char c, int i){

    if (c<'a' || c>'j' || i > 9 || i<0){
        throw invalid_argument("invalid input");
    }

    Ship* ship = shipAt(i, c-'a');


    if (ship) {
        score[i][c-'a']= '*';
    }
    else{
        score[i][c-'a']= 'x';
    }
}

Ship* Board::shipAt(int x, int y){
    Ship* ship = Ship::includes(x,y);

    if (ship){
            return ship;   
        }
    else{
        return NULL;
         }
}

int Board::level(void)
{
    int lev = 0;
    std::vector<Ship *>::iterator iter = shipList.begin();
    std::vector<Ship *>::iterator end = shipList.end();
    for ( ; iter != end; ++iter )
    {
       lev += (*iter)->level();
    }

    return lev;

}
```

Essentially I was trying to use the `bool Ship::includes(int x, int y)`function from the Ship class. I was trying to make it so that if the function was returned true then the atShip function would return true as well since the includes function is a boolean.

However, that implementation is not working and I am receiving a call to non-static member function without an object argument error.

**EDIT:** For additional context (may be unnecessary so don't click unless you need to),

Here is my Ship.cpp:  http://pastebin.com/cYDt0f8W

Here is my Ship header file: http://pastebin.com/W6vwKJRz

Here is my Board header file:http://pastebin.com/r36YjHjt

Answer (score 1):

`Ship* ship = Ship::includes(x,y);`

1. `Ship::includes()` returns a `bool` not a `Ship*`
2. `Ship::includes()` is not `static`

You need to go through your list of ships and for each one test it it is "at" (x,y). Once you find a ship that is, you can return it.

Something like (pseudo code):

```
foreach ship in shipList
    if (ship->includes(x, y))
        return ship
return NULL;
```